# Does the type of informational representation of a question in a research survey affect answers?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, survey

Does the type of data format used to represent questions in empirical research affect the depth and quality of that research? For example, most questionnaires use written text as a data format. Would results differ if the same questions, under the same rules, were asked in person for example? I have memories of some platform presenting survey questions in a game-like interface, e.g. instead of asking you in text if you would rather purchase a cup of coffee over a cup of tea with five dollars, it displayed dollar banknotes as images and you had to move them with the mouse cursor towards either the image of a cup of tea or the image of a cup of coffee.

(My own speculation is that questions should be in a data format as close as possible to the data format used in the actual event we are researching about, but yet I am not certain that this would necessarily bring the highest possible fidelity to what's in the mind of the respondent.)